# Android best way to parse and add xml items in SQLite DB?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a 800 kb xml file on a server. I download it, and parse with a SAXParser. 
And then i add all item elements to my SQLLite db on the phone.

All item has 50-60 element. 
One insert query take about:

11-18 21:15:54.079: ERROR/448 delay_*(9169): 41207
11-18 21:15:54.099: ERROR/448 delay*__(9169): __ 41223

about 20-90ms , i have 500 row, and it takes 40 minutes, it is a good value for this?

How i can do it faster? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your INSERTs in transactions. By default, each INSERT is a transaction and involves writing to flash. You get better results on bulk data loads by having fewer transactions. For 500 rows, perhaps do one transaction per 100 rows or something.

Comment: agree with the previous; also noting play with the number of rows per transaction, 100 with one insert might be fastest; 20 with another; so just fiddle.